# Modify DCFG to enforce length limit

Tags: fl.formal-languages, automata-theory, context-free, grammars

Given a deterministic context-free grammar $G$ that generates the language $L$, is there an efficient algorithm that can be used to construct another DCFG $G_N$ that generates the language $\{ s \in L \mid \lvert s \lvert \leq N \}$? In other words, an algorithm that creates a DCFG whose language is the set of valid strings from $L$ that are under a certain length $N$.

For the algorithm, what would be the size of $G_N$ in terms of $N$? I'm especially interested if there are algorithms that result in $G_N$ of size $O(N)$ or even $O(N^2)$.

I'm also interested if there are arguments, perhaps heuristic ones, for a lower bound on the size of $G_N$. Because DCFG's can be parsed efficiently, I suspect $O(N)$ is possible, but maybe I'm wrong and adding the length limit forces a worst case of $O(N^3)$.

Comment: If you convert $G$ to a DPDA (e.g., a LR(1) parser), then add a counter to the state of the DPDA, then convert the DPDA back to a CFG, does this achieve a CFG of size $O(N)$?

Comment: @D.W. Great to see you, I see this approach is related to your algorithm [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/148133), which I found really helpful elsewhere! However, I think the conversion from DPDA to CFG would make the grammar much bigger than $O(N)$, I only found mentions of a $O(N^3)$ conversion method. I don't know if DCFG's are smaller if converted the same way.